# how to custumize embedded video next-video/mux

Tags: video, next.js13, mux-video

I was looking for most optimal way to embed videos in my next js project. I found mux/next-video, how can I get rid of the badge on the video?

[image]

and how do I customize video player further? I mean make it autoplay or play on loop, or muted?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Community Lead at Mux here.

Mux assets will include a "badge"/overlay until you proceed to set up your Mux account with a credit card. Once you do that, you'll receive $20 in credits and the overlay will be removed.

For the video autoplaying/looping, you can use the same attributes that are supported by the native HTML5 video element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attributes